# Remote Access Trojan in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, trojan

**Note:** *I have already posted this to ubuntu forums but I have not received an answer. I was given advice that information security is a better place for such a topic even if it's ubuntu-related*

### Introduction

I'm kinda new to ubuntu but I have switched to it from Windows since I have heard that it's more secure and more virus-free. In the last few months, I have read a lot about computer viruses and it probably made me a bit more paranoid.

### The problem

What are the chances of getting a *Remote Access Trojan (RAT)*? I have noticed several times that when I left my room for a while another window/program I did not touch was opened and since my computer contains a lot of source codes, I would consider it as 'end-of-my-life' if I was infected.

### Additional Information

- I have uninstalled VNC (vino) from my machine right after the system installation
- I have not download anything unknown from the internet, only a few well-known programs using official packages with `apt-get install`
- I have not visited any websites I would not be sure about (my ubuntu is only used for programming)
- I use ClamAV scanning tool every morning `clamscan -r --bell -i /`

### Solutions I have already heard about but I have not really tested them

- Using `wireshark` to monitor traffic (I am not experienced with using this tool I would like to know what kind of data should I be looking for)
- I have also heard that `iptables` might be useful

### Ending

I know that you can never be 100% sure that your computer is virus free, but I think having a RAT in your computer is kind of 'extreme virus'. To be honest, I doubt that someone would really be controlling my PC since I am sure there is no real way for him to do it, but on the other hand I'm still paranoid about this. Is there any way I can really check it and then finally close this case which eats a lot of my time searching security forums etc... ?

Comment: Typically, you should wait to have your question migrated here from the moderators. Part of the problem here is that the question is too broad. You are seeing unusual activity and want to figure out if it is something malicious. We can't really give you a definitive answer. We are also not tech support. Is it always the same program that runs by itself? Is it always a different program? Is your ClamAV up to date?

Comment: it is laptop so maybe a bad touchpad driver might also cause some trouble and yes clam av is up to date

Comment: @schroeder AV is pointless on an already compromised machine, not to mention that Clam is designed to detect Windows malware (by scanning email, etc) and does not even have real-time protection.

Comment: why pointless ? it detects where is the infected file which allows the attacker to connect and it will delete it , or no ?

Comment: The only way to be (almost) sure would be to observe the machine's network traffic using another computer.

Comment: @Tomas the issue is, it's aimed at detecting Windows malware as far as I know (to be used to scan incoming email, downloads, etc for a Windows network). It will not do anything against Linux malware, not to mention there's a great chance your potential malware is either a custom variant or has been obfuscated so existing signatures don't match, and Clam doesn't offer heuristic scans.

Comment: but tell me honestly we all know that there are just a few linux viruses do you think that RATS do exist for linuxes also ? by rat i mean teamweaver with access to everything but without the user knowing that the teamviewer session has been created , i use 'teamviewer' just to explain i mean that the rat virus shares destkop etc..

Comment: @AndréBorie of course, but if this AV is not up to date, then we can make some other assumptions about the situation. Think "[Brown M&Ms](http://www.snopes.com/music/artists/vanhalen.asp)" Not all questions are about the facts they ask for ...

Comment: Please don't cross-post. http://askubuntu.com/questions/820791/remote-access-trojan-in-ubuntu

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross-posted and you have accepted an answer on the other post.